# Using closure in the function

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I like to know that whether there is a way to use a `closure` in the function `updateView()`, so that the code is `not repeated` for `phone` and `pad` in the code below. Here the closure should have `parameters` for `width` and `height`

```
  @IBInspectable var leftImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

func updateView() {
    if let image = leftImage
    {
        leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone)
        {
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.tintColor = color
            leftView = imageView
        }
        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad)
        {
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.tintColor = color
            leftView = imageView
        }
    }
    else
    {
        leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.never
        leftView = nil
    }
}
```

I ran out of ideas, trying it unsuccessfully. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: why need of a closure here? I think you can simply assign `width` and `height` in if else condition and move the imageview creation setting values out side.

Comment: you are changing only frame according to device type, I would prefer using a local common var for frame, and change it according the device!

Comment: @ShivamGaur, thats a good idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is identical except for the image view size. Set a variable for the size based on the device and don't repeat any of the other code.

```
func updateView() {
    if let image = leftImage {
        leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
        let size: CGFloat = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? 20 : 30
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.tintColor = color
        leftView = imageView
    } else {
        leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.never
        leftView = nil
    }
}
```

BTW - don't write code that makes decisions based on the device idiom. Make your decisions based on the size of the view controller's view.

Comment: Never even thought of this solution. Was thinking way too deep.

Comment: @rmaddy, will keep in mind about not to make decisions based on device idiom. Thanks :)